# Can I use Bray-Curtis distance when performing MRPP or MRBP?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, nonparametric, distance

Can I use Bray-Curtis distance when performing MRPP (Multi-response Permutation Procedures) or MRBP (Blocked Multi-response Permutation Procedures)?

[See Ch 24 of [McCune & Grace (2002)](http://www.umass.edu/landeco/teaching/multivariate/readings/McCune.and.Grace.2002.chapte24.pdf) for explanation of MRPP & MRBP].

Typically, according to McCune & Grace and the literature they cite, Euclidean, Squared Euclidean and Sorensen distance are most often used for these procedures. My question is whether Bray-Curtis Distance would also be appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

You can use non-euclidean distances such as Bray-Curtis if you use Pseudo-F as your test statistic (see Reiss et al 2010, Biometrics, Vol. 66 (2), pp. 636-643).

"the pseudo-F statistic is a generalization of the classical F statistic that can be calculated directly from the distance matrix D, whether or not D is Euclidean."

The authors of the vegan package in R recommend using the function "adonis", which uses a permutation test with pseudo-F ratios, rather than mrpp. You might want to look into using adonis instead.